# C/C++: How to check if an array is static or dynamic during runtime

Tags: c++, c, arrays, runtime

I am wondering how can I check an array is static or dynamically allocated. I looked up online and found the following implementation in [mysql source code](http://www.iskm.org/mysql56/my__sys_8h_source.html), I don't know why this works ? (line 0303 checks if the array is static)

```
       /*

0301     Just mark as empty if we are using a static buffer
0302   */
0303   if (array->buffer == (uchar *)(array + 1))
0304     array->elements= 0;
```

This is the definition of DYNAMIC_ARRAY in mysql :

```
341  
342 typedef struct st_dynamic_array
343 { 
344     uchar *buffer; 
345     uint elements,max_element; 
346     uint alloc_increment; 
347     uint size_of_element; 
348 } DYNAMIC_ARRAY;
```

Comment: There is some missing context around those statements such as the definition and type of `array`.

Comment: Don't check. Just don't throw away the information in the first place. A good way to handle dynamic arrays is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: This is the definition of DYNAMIC_ARRAY in mysql :  
  341 
  342 typedef struct st_dynamic_array
  343 {
  344   uchar *buffer;
  345   uint elements,max_element;
  346   uint alloc_increment;
  347   uint size_of_element;
  348 } DYNAMIC_ARRAY;

Comment: @AliQajar can you link to the source you copied this from?

Comment: this is where DYNAMIC_ARRAY is defined   http://www.iskm.org/mysql56/my__sys_8h_source.html

Comment: One cannot confirm whether a variable is static or dynamic without knowing more information, such as the address range of static memory or the range of addresses of dynamic memory.  Then again, nothing is stopping the compiler from placing static variable next to dynamic variables.

Comment: and this is where it is being allocated and deleted. http://osxr.org:8080/mysql/source/mysys/array.c

Comment: Good question. Is your question specific to indeterministic data? If yes I would amuse the answer is no. How can the compiler be aware of arbitrary data?

Comment: @AliQajar:  Code always looks better when placed into your question and not in the comments.  Look at my edit to your question.

Comment: @ Thomas Matthews; Sure. Thank you for editing the question and for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

You're missing some context here. *In this particular case*, it's known that either `array->buffer` points to `(uchar*)(array + 1)` and is statically allocated, *or* it points somewhere else and is dynamically allocated.

But there's nothing about `(uchar*)(array + 1)` that automatically means something is statically allocated.

It's like asking how this function finds the length of the array (which is that *it doesn't*, unless the array ends with a 0):

```
int getArrayLength(int *a)
{
    for(int i = 0; ; i++)
        if(a[i] == 0)
            return i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't - without additional information.

For C, an array is just a bunch of memory addresses. `a[n]` actually means `(type(a))*((void*)&a+n*sizeof(a))`. It couldn't care less about how (or if) it was allocated, even whether the addresses are real.

The additional information may be:

- the variable is of a specific type which has fields you can check for the information you want

  - this is your case: the code you supplied "knows" the variable is `DYNAMIC_ARRAY`
- getting hints from the allocation system

  - e.g. `free` and `realloc` are only supposed to be called with pointers previously given by `malloc`. Checking a pointer's validity, however, isn't a part of the public interface

    - Debugging tools like `valgrind`, however, typically wrap the functions with a checker to validate the use of the routines

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain what the mysql source code snippet is doing, which may help you.

Firstly it is **not** a test for statically allocated arrays.  It attempts to test if an array and header were allocated contiguously ( one immediately following the other ).

```
if (array->buffer == (uchar *)(array + 1))
    array->elements= 0;
```

This is actually taking a pointer to the structure `DYNAMIC_ARRAY` and checks if the address of the array is pointing to the address immediately after the structure itself.

One way the test will be true is if the structure and array space were allocate in one single malloc() - a contiguous block.  For example :

```
DYNAMIC_ARRAY *dap = NULL ;

dap = malloc( sizeof(DYNAMIC_ARRAY) + arraylength ) ;
dap->buffer = (uchar *)(dap+1) ;
```

This, IMO, is an unsafe piece of code, as it makes a dangerous assumption.

It assumes that two separate allocations, one of a header structure and one of array space, cannot follow each other in memory.  This is outside of the control of the application, unless they've explicitly coded their own memory manager to not do that.

If this trick is being used elsewhere in the mysql sources I'd be quite alarmed, as it's just asking for trouble.

Comment: That was very informative. Now I see what is going on. The line that I copied was used a couple of times for memory management in array.c: it is accessible through  the following link: http://osxr.org:8080/mysql/source/mysys/array.c